# Why would a replica not be listed as a Kafka broker?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Thanks to `confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient`, I was inspecting the configuration of replicas in my cluster

```
# meta is kafka's ClusterMetadata
for partition_id, partition in meta.topics[topic].partitions.items():
  for repl in partition.replicas:
    if repl not in meta.brokers:
      print("replica not in broker")
```

And I see that some replicas are in partitions but not part of the "brokers".

What does it mean? Are the replicas still replicating their leader? What's the impact on the partition?

Edit: We have 1024 partitions and 3 replicas per partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears that the "missing" replicas were referring to machines that were stopped/dead

Answer (score 0):

What is the replication factor of your topic? How large is the cluster?

If these aren't equal, then you would have some brokers not hosting at least one replica for a certain topic

In other words, `replication.factor <= len(meta.brokers)`

Comment: Good question, I should have mentioned:
We have 1024 partitions and 3 replicas per partition

Comment: Okay, but more than 3 brokers?

Comment: yes, hundreds of brokers

Comment: Okay, so have you compared `len(partition.replicas)` and `len(meta.brokers)`? Why are you expecting all replicas to be on all brokers?

Comment: so we have 79 brokers total (that's `len(meta.brokers)`) and 1024 partitions; 
All partitions have exactly 3 replicas. We have different 80 replicas total (`set(x for partition in meta.topics['topic_name'].partitions.values() for x in partition.replicas)`)
So it means that some partitions have the 80th replica (that's not a broker)
What does it mean for those partitions? What does it mean for a replica not to be one of the brokers? Does it mean the replica isn't replicating anything?

Comment: hi, any idea? do you need more information?

Comment: Replication is working fine if you are monitoring ISR shrinks and out-of-sync replicas elsewhere using JMX. Don't use Python for this.... Brokers can hold multiple partitions, but never multiple replicas on the same broker, and are not guaranteed to be equally distributed over the cluster

Comment: thanks. Not sure if I understood your last answer but what happens is some machines were dead. Thanks anyways for bearing with me

Comment: 1) Your question is using Python to loop over some stuff. If you are doing this to check some replication data, then that's fine, but JMX metrics already show you overall cluster details if there are out-of-sync replicas (or down brokers) 2) Not sure how else I can say that not all brokers will have the same number of replicas, or all permutations of partition-replicas for your topic will be placed on every broker

Comment: yep, I got that last part: brokers will own many partitions. I will try out JMX, thanks for the tip